# Using Observable Zip misbehaving

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have two observables(A, B), and I want the first to finish running before the second runs. But, that's not even the problem I'm having. The problem is that, when A is added before B, B doesn't run at all unless I place B before A then, the two runs. But, the scenario I'm in is like thus:

- A - Pickup
- B - Delivery

There are three types of orders. `Pickup Only`, `Delivery Only` and `Pickup And Delivery`. `Pickups` need to run before `Deliveries` in every situation. A `Delivery` only already have `Pickup` marked as `true`. A `Pickup` only, needs to be `picked up and delivered` on it being closed. Which is why I need `Pickup` to send all locally saved pickups first before sending deliveries. So, I did this:

**Pickup**

```
private Observable<UpdateMainResponse> getDeliveredOrders() {

    String token = PrefUtil.getToken(context);

    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pageControl = BehaviorSubject.create(1);
    Observable<UpdateMainResponse> ret = pageControl.asObservable().concatMap(integer -> {

        if (integer - 1 != deliveryUpdate.size()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "DeliveredOrders: " + deliveryUpdate.size());
            RealmOrderUpdate theDel = deliveryUpdate.get(integer-1);
            Log.e(TAG, "DeliveryUpdate: " + theDel.toString());
            DeliverOrder pickupOrder = new DeliverOrder();
            pickupOrder.setUuid(theDel.getUuid());
            pickupOrder.setCode(theDel.getDest_code());
            pickupOrder.setDelivered_lat(theDel.getLoc_lat());
            pickupOrder.setDelivered_long(theDel.getLoc_long());
            return apiService.deliverOrder(theDel.getOrderId(), token, pickupOrder)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
                    .doOnNext(updateMainResponse -> {
                        try {
                            Log.e(TAG, updateMainResponse.toString());
                            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> theDel.deleteFromRealm());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            pageControl.onNext(integer + 1);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            return Observable.<UpdateMainResponse>empty().doOnCompleted(pageControl::onCompleted);
        }
    });

    return Observable.defer(() -> ret);
}
```

**Delivery**

```
private Observable<UpdateMainResponse> getPickedOrders() {

    Log.e(TAG, "PickedOrders: " + pickUpdate.size());

    String token = PrefUtil.getToken(context);

    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pageControl = BehaviorSubject.create(1);
    Observable<UpdateMainResponse> ret = pageControl.asObservable().concatMap(integer -> {

        Log.e(TAG, "MainPickedInteger: " + integer);
        if (integer - 1 != pickUpdate.size()) {
            RealmOrderUpdate thePick = pickUpdate.get(integer - 1);
            Log.e(TAG, "PickedUpdate: " + thePick.toString());
            PickupOrder pickupOrder = new PickupOrder();
            pickupOrder.setUuid(thePick.getUuid());
            pickupOrder.setCode(thePick.getSource_code());
            pickupOrder.setPicked_lat(thePick.getLoc_lat());
            pickupOrder.setPicked_long(thePick.getLoc_long());
            return apiService.pickupOrder(thePick.getOrderId(), token, pickupOrder)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
                    .doOnNext(updateMainResponse -> {
                        try {
                            Log.e(TAG, updateMainResponse.toString());
                            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> thePick.deleteFromRealm());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            pageControl.onNext(integer + 1);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            return Observable.<UpdateMainResponse>empty().doOnCompleted(pageControl::onCompleted);
        }
    });

    return Observable.defer(() -> ret);
}
```

**Zipper**

```
private Observable<ZipperResponse> batchedZip() {
    return Observable.zip(getPickedOrders(), getDeliveredOrders(), (updateMainResponse, updateMainResponse2) -> {
        List<UpdateMainResponse> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        bakeries.add(updateMainResponse);
        bakeries.add(updateMainResponse2);
        return new ZipperResponse(orders);
    });
}
```

**Utilizing Zipper**

```
public void generalUpload(APIRequestListener listener) {

    batchedZip.subscribe(new Subscriber<ZipperResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            listener.didComplete();
            unsubscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            listener.handleDefaultError(e);
            unsubscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ZipperResponse zipperResponse) {
            Log.e(TAG, zipperResponse.size());
        }
    });
}
```

**Problem**

1. I don't know why `getDeliveredOrders()` doesn't get called unless I move it to the first before `getPickedOrders()`
2. Reading through [Rx Documentation for Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) I can see that it's not going to work as I expected where all of `getPickedOrders()` runs first before `getDeliveredOrders()` runs. It'll have to do it one by one. E.g: One of Pickup and then One of Delivery

Any help to understand what's going on would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if I got that right:

- Pickup only: need to run through the Pickup process, then they complete.
- Delivery only: need to run through the Delivery process, then they complete.
- Pickup and Delivery: need to run through Pickup first, then through Delivery.

On a very high level, almost preudo-code, why does this process not work?

```
Observable<Item> performPickup(Item item);
Observable<Item> performDelivery(Item item);
Observable<Items> items = ...;

items
.flatMap(item -> item.needsPickup() ? performPickup(item) : Observable.just(item))
.flatMap(item -> item.needsDelivery() ? performDelivery(item) : Observable.just(item))
.doOnNext(completedItem -> ...)
```

If you have different sources for the three types:

```
Observable<Item> items = Observable.merge(
     pickupSource(),
     deliverySource(),
     pickupAndDeliverySource());
```

Comment: Are you saying I should use a `.merge` instead of a `.zip`. Mind you, I don't need this `pickupAndDeliverySource()` because why? In a situation where that is the case, I just store `pickup and delivery` so, no need for that. It always falls to making sure `pickup` goes first before `delivery`

Comment: Then don't use the 3rd parameter. On a high level, is what I describe what you want to do? Or do you want to collect everything first, run all the pickup tasks and then all the delivery tasks?

Comment: Actually, that's what I had in mind and what I did. Because this guy `pickUpdate` is an initialized `List<PickedOrder>` `pickUpdate = realm.where(RealmOrderUpdate.class).equalTo("pickup", true).findAll();` and I use the `BehaviorSubject` to loop through to send all `pickups`

Comment: I'm going through Rx Documentation and I think `merge` is the way to go. `Merge may interleave the items emitted by the merged Observables (a similar operator, Concat, does not interleave items, but emits all of each source Observable’s items in turn before beginning to emit items from the next source Observable).` That's from there documentation. Which if I get it right, it means it runs through the first loop before the next right?

Comment: Don't think in terms of loops, think in terms of data dependencies. Is your  requirement that you have absolute ordering between `Pickup only` and `Delivery only` jobs? Then the only way you can get that is to do a sort after you have *all* the jobs, so the best way to do that is `merge`, `toList`, `sort`. However I get the impression this is not the case.

Comment: Now, I get you. Absolute ordering is not needed. Just to make sure all pickups are completed before deliveries. Thanks for the shared knowledge.